# Difference between File.load and File.read in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sass

I am trying to follow Sass -> CSS converter code on [Sass website](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Engine.html#render-instance_method).

```
template = File.load('stylesheets/sassy.sass')
sass_engine = Sass::Engine.new(template)
output = sass_engine.render
puts output
```

And I get this error while I'm trying to `File.load`

```
SyntaxError in PublishController#index

/Users/jkim/rails/support-rhapsody/app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass:1: target of repeat operator is not specified: /* http:/
/Users/jkim/rails/support-rhapsody/app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass:2: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
   v2.0 | 20110126
      ^
/Users/jkim/rails/support-rhapsody/app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass:2: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
   v2.0 | 20110126
       ^
/Users/jkim/rails/support-rhapsody/app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
   License: none (public domain) */
```

But when I do File.read, it works fine until `output = sass_engine.render`.

I get this error,

```
NoMethodError in PublishController#index

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

What's the difference between File.read and File.load? And if you know how to fix this problem in Sass, even better.

Comment: Did you try `ri File.load` and `ri File.read`? The two methods have very different uses.

Comment: `ri File.load` gets `NoMethodError: private method `load' called for File:Class`. And 
`ri File.read` gets `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..4)`

Comment: you shouldn't type in `ri` in the IRB prompt.  It is a separate shell command that gives you rdoc information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in the Ruby Kernel method `#load` it means evaluate the text loaded as code which is what it looks like is being done here.  `File.read` loads the text as a String.

From sass docs for `Sass::Engine.new`

> Creates a new Engine. Note that Engine should only be used directly when compiling in-memory Sass code. If you’re compiling a single Sass file from the filesystem, use Sass::Engine.for_file. If you’re compiling multiple files from the filesystem, use Sass::Plugin.

So do that.